# Updating Approvers list dynamically in Azure Devops Release Job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Here is my scenario:

My release job has multiple stages, and for one of the stages, I need to add an approver (to the existing list of approvers) dynamically by querying an external API. Currently we are manually updating the release by editing it. I am trying to automate this using Powershell, so by running this script in the preceding stage, I can update the approver for the succeeding stage.

I tried using Update Release API, but it seems not to be working. One of the errors I got is `"Invalid input to update stage 'Prod' of release 'Release-18'. Make sure you have pending approvals in the stage` which is when deployment to that particular stage is yet to start (deployment is currently running in previous stages)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: It seems there's invalid parameter value in your request body, please share your request body if possible, for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-the-release